# Here Map tested with Jest throws InvalidArgumentError: H.util.Cache#setMaxSize

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, here-api, babel-jest

I'm trying to test my Here Map component in React. My setup follows the guide pretty closely. Everything works fine in production. I'm using babel to transform the JS package `@here/maps-api-for-javascript`.

When running my tests I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: H.util.Cache#setMaxSize (Argument #0 0)

      34 |     })
      35 |     const layers = platform.createDefaultLayers()
    > 36 |     const map = new H.Map(ref.current, layers.vector.normal.map, {
         |                 ^
      37 |       pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
      38 |       center: { lat: 6.6111, lng: 20.9394 },
      39 |       zoom: 5
```

My `jest.config.js` is as follows:

```
{
  "bail": true,
  "collectCoverageFrom": ["**/src/**/*.ts?(x)", "!**/src/index.tsx"],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "verbose": true,
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "setupFiles": ["./scripts/env-setup.ts"],
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./scripts/jest.setup.ts", "jest-canvas-mock"],
  "testMatch": ["**/src/**/*.test.ts?(x)"],
  "transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!(@here|bar)/)"],
  "transform": { "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest" }
}
```

The test is as simple as `expect(mapWrapper).toBeTruthy()`

Not sure where to start debugging this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It probably could be related to the configuration in the project setup or babel transform. Sorry that it is hard to say anything conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the positive values  to the new H.util.Cache method, That is why it is throwing error.

The cache represents an in-memory LRU-cache with a fixed size. Once the elements held in the cache reach the maximum permitted size, the cache drops the elements with the oldest retrieval time stamp to bring the size of the cached data within bounds. Data elements held in the cache are stored with their IDs and size to facilitate retrieval.

Name    Type    Description
maxSize number
A value indicating the maximum size of the cache

opt_onDrop  function(string, ?, number) optional
A callback to be invoked when a data element is dropped from the cache

opt_filter  function    optional
A function to filter data elements that are not to be cached

For more details, please check the [GUIDE](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.35.3/api_reference/H.util.Cache.html)